# Where the decoded frame by ffmepg stored?

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I try to decode video and convert frame to rgb32 or gb565le format.

Then pass this frame from C to Android buffer by JNI.

So far, I know to how pass buffer from C to Android as well as how to decode video and get decoded frame.

**My question is how to convert decoded frame to rgb32 (or rgb565le) and where is it stored?**

The following is my code, I'm not sure is correct or not.

-Jargo

---

```
img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, 100, 100, PIX_FMT_RGB32, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(!img_convert_ctx) return -6;

while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
   // Is this a packet from the video stream?
   if(packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
       avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

       // Did we get a video frame?
       if(frameFinished) {
            AVPicture pict;

            if(avpicture_alloc(&pict, PIX_FMT_RGB32, 100, 100) >= 0) {
                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, (const uint8_t * const *)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pict.data, pict.linesize);
            }
       } // End of if( frameFinished )
   } // End of if( packet.stream_index == videoStream )

   // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
   av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The decoded frame goes into `pict`. (`pFrame` is a raw frame.)

`100x100` is probably no good you have to calculate `pict` size based on pFrame size.
I guess it should be `pFrame->width*pFrame->height*32;`

You have to allocate `pict` yourself.

See this tutorial http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: You mean, after `sws_scale` the converted frame data is stored in `pict.data`? What meas of allocate `pict`? Like this `avpicture_fill(&pict, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB32, 100, 100);`?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. In that tutorial there's an example.